# Rails disable and enable remote links based on an event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

What's the best way to enable a remote link on an event?

I have a remote link that loads a form. After the form loads, I want the link to remain disabled until the form is either submitted or a cancel link is clicked. UJS's `data-disable-with` only disables the link for the life of the request, meaning clicking the link multiple times loads multiple forms.

Is there a way to do this with UJS or do I have to roll my own JS?

```
= link_to "Edit", edit_project_path(@project), remote: true, 'data-disable-with' => "Wait"
```

The link loads this form:

```
= form_for @project, remote: request.xhr? do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = content_tag :a, "Cancel", data: { removes: 'project-form' }
  = f.submit
```

Clicking the cancel link removes the form.

```
$('.project-summary').on 'click', '[data-removes="project-form"]', ->
  $(this).parents('form').remove();
```

Comment: What version are you using of Rails?

Comment: take a look at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag#1305--disable-with-is-deprecated and it will say that from version 3.2.5 upwards this has been deprecated

Comment: That does not affect me. I am using `data-disable-with` which is not deprecated. `disable_with` is.

Comment: I just need a way to stop the user from loading multiple forms by click the button repeatedly. I guess i could just hide the link.

Comment: indeed you could hide the link once the submit button has been pressed